# SQLAlchemy approximate count without making query

Tags: python, mysql, sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy

With PostgresSQL and MySQL databases I can use EXPLAIN in front of query and it will return me a query plan, which contains the approximate number of rows that query result will have. For PostresSql for example:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM foo WHERE i = 4;

                         QUERY PLAN
--------------------------------------------------------------
 Index Scan using fi on foo  (cost=0.00..5.98 rows=100 width=4)
   Index Cond: (i = 4)
```

This plan contains `rows=100` which tells me that this query will return approximately 100 rows.
For MS SQL Server I can use `SET SHOWPLAN_XML ON`, create a query and there is a number in the report that tells approximate numbers of rows.

I was looking if there is something similar in SQLAlchemy. I would like somehow get the number of rows (count) for any select query and it should be the same for any database (so writing a raw SQL is not the option). In SQLAlchemy I am using SQL Expression Language, not ORM.

So the question is how to write a Python function which gets the SQL Alchemy query (with type `sqlalchemy.sql.selectable.Select`) at the input and returns the approximate number of rows for this query without making an actual query?

This function would look like this:

```
def count_approx(self, query):  # query type: sqlalchemy.sql.selectable.Select
    # how to get count?
    return count
```

Comment: A few articles I've seen about query plans seemed to suggest that, depending on the complexity of the query and the information available to the optimizer, those rowcount estimates can be way off.

Comment: @GordThompson I know that. I actually do not need an exact number. The approximation would be helpful enough. Also, any other suggestion about how to get a fast count would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

An easy approach to get the aproximate number of rows of a table is to use the database system's catalogue (As far as I know, EXPLAIN uses the same).

For MySQL this would look like:

```
SELECT TABLE_ROWS 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'foo'
```

Comment: It would be helpful in cases with simple queries - only one table in a query. I am actually looking for the solution how to do that for any query (also more complex queries with more tables joined).